# How to prevent method with @postcontruct annotation from being executed during server startup

Tags: spring-mvc, jsf-2

I am developing a web-application using JSF2.1 and Spring MVC. I have written @PostConstruct for methods which i need to execute on page load. The beans are all ViewScoped. But the problem is that the method is executed on server startup and initialized then and the same instance is used during page load. Is there any way to get the method to run only during page load ?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear (I mean I don't understand why a `@PostConstructor` in a **viewscoped** managed bean will be called on server startup at all), but you could possibly replace the postconstructor with a `<f:viewParam/>` to manually call the same method on page load. I'd look deeper into the design of the app if I were you

Comment: That sure is one way of doing it. But as far as I have read and understood, the @postConstruct method should work in this case. The invocation at server startup is something i wanted to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when you're running the server from inside an IDE like Eclipse. The IDE's server plugin such as Eclipse Tomcat plugin will after the startup process do a self-test by sending a GET request to `/`. Apparently you've on `/` a page associated with those view scoped beans.

Ignore it. This wouldn't happen during production.

Comment: I am executing it using a maven plugin (maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin). is the above mentioned behaviour to be expected in this case too ? No server plugins or adapters in eclipse are being used.